# Python - plotting week-wise distribution

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, plotly

I have a dataframe which looks like:

```
       date
1      2008-10-05
10     2007-03-30
100    2008-07-05
1000   2007-03-30
1001   2014-08-14
1002   2007-09-30
1003   2007-06-14
1004   2006-01-13
1005   2006-08-04
1006   2007-06-14
1007   2008-11-30
```

What I want to do is plot a histogram which shows the dates distribution scaled down to a week. 
For example,
The index is say a picture ID, I want to drill down to visualize how many pictures were taken in the first week of October of year 2006. I want a weekly histogram in other words.

`df['week'].iplot(kind='histogram')` only gives back the week number but I want to tie it back to the year.

It would be great if someone could help me to plot the histogram using plot.ly. A matplotlib plot will also do.

Thanks for your help.

Edit: Below is the final solution to my problem:

```
df_new = df.groupby(['year','week']).count()['date']
df_dict = df_new.to_dict()
df_tups = [(' wk#'.join(map(str,key)), df_dict[key]) for key in df_dict.keys()]
df_tups = sorted(df_tups, key=lambda x : (x[0], x[1]))
x = ["'"+tup[0][2:] for tup in df_tups]
y = [tup[1] for tup in df_tups]
trace1 = go.Bar(
            x = x,
            y = y
        )

data = [trace1]
layout = go.Layout(
    xaxis=dict(tickangle=45)
)
fig = dict(data=data, layout=layout)
py.iplot(fig)
```

Comment: Can you add the column names to your dataframe?

Comment: Sure, absolutely. @MaximilianPeters

Comment: In your sample data there is no 'week' column or am I missing something?

Comment: @MaximilianPeters: I wish to calculate the week histogram. What is the point of having a week and put a week number there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let your df be:

```
df =    date
7   2012-06-11
3   2012-09-28
19  2012-10-01
2   2012-10-03
6   2012-12-22
1   2013-02-19
9   2013-02-28
12  2013-03-12
4   2013-04-04
17  2013-04-18
11  2013-05-17
5   2013-07-07
14  2013-10-22
13  2014-01-16
15  2014-02-25
18  2014-03-19
0   2014-03-31
16  2014-04-01
8   2014-04-27
10  2014-09-20
```

What you want to do is:

```
df['week'] = df['date'].map(lambda x: x.isocalendar()[1])
df['year'] = df['date'].map(lambda x: x.isocalendar()[0])
data = df.groupby(['year','week']).count()
```

that wld give you:

```
        date
year    week   count    
2012    24       1
        39       1
        40       2
        51       1
2013    8        1
        9        1
        11       1
        14       1
        16       1
        20       1
        27       1
        43       1
2014    3        1
        9        1
        12       1
        14       2
        17       1
        38       1
```

Now, if you want to histogram, you can do per year, or you can do overall period. but you would have to add 52 weeks to each year for each year its higher than the first year in your set(years), otherwise it wld mix up week numbers of different years

Answer (score 1):

When a column of a dataframe / a Series is of type `datetime`, you have a special accessor `dt` to apply vectorized datetime functions (the same approach as the `str` special accessor for string series). Use this feature to obtain the grouping you expect:

```
df.groupby([df.date.dt.year, df.date.dt.week]).size()
Out[16]: 
date  date
2006  2       1
      31      1
2007  13      2
      24      2
      39      1
2008  27      1
      40      1
      48      1
2014  33      1
dtype: int64
```